# Resultset returns 160 but database returns 44 rows; WHY

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I am querying my SQL database and have discovered that when I ask for 160 rows, and the database only has 44 rows, `ResultSet` returns 160 rows. When this happens, the first 44 rows have actual useful numeric values and the remaining 116 rows have values that are all `0`. How do I get `ResultSet` to only contain or provide me with the 44 rows that are returned from the database query? Here is the code fragment:

```
statement = connection.createStatement();

query = "SELECT " + "Close" + ", Volume" + " FROM source_data_manager.TradingData_daily WHERE Exchange = '" + exchange + 
   "' and Symbol = '" + symbol + "' order by EntryID DESC limit " + 160 + ";";

//Execute the query
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
//Loop through the results
int    count  = 0;
while (resultSet.next())
{
   valuesRetrieved[count++] = resultSet.getDouble(1);
   volume += resultSet.getLong(2);
}
```

Coming out of this loop, count is equal to `160` but should equal to `44`. The array `valuesRetrieved[]` has 44 elements of actual usable values, and the remaining 114 values all equal to zero (`0`). The array should only have 44 values in it.

Comment: What king of DB you are using?

Comment: Run your query directly against the db and see how many rows you get.

Comment: Show us how you declared `valuesRetrieved`, if you declared using `double[] valuesRetrieved = new double[160]`, your trailing `0` comes from it not from your query result

Comment: BTW the remaining should be `116` not `114`

Comment: I am using the SQL libraries for Java that "default" for netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Statement.setMaxRows`

```
void setMaxRows(int max) throws SQLException;
```

The advantage of `setMaxRows` is that you can create general statements, valid for Postgres, Oracle, Mysql etc.

In fact, Oracle is using `ROWNUM` syntax, postgres - `LIMIT`, msqsql - `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, might it be driver specific reaction to limit without fetch size? 
What would `resultSet.isAfterLast()`return for empty rows?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. Nicholas Filotto had the correct answer. In the top of the method is the declaration of valuesRetrieved as follows:

double [] valuesReceived = new double [160];

The problem is fixed by not using the statement:

valuesReceived[count++] = resultSet.getDouble(1);

There is one additional peculiarity. I must not understand what getFetchSize() does because the statement:

int xxx = resultSet.getFetchSize();

always results in 0 being assigned to xxx.... Don't really understand why.